# Arrange a numpy array to represent physical arrangement with 2d color plot

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 2d numpy array that is representative of a physical set of pixels. However, the pixels themselves are arranged in a very complex manner, and I'm having trouble arranging the array so that a color plot will represent the physical setup. Here is the layout of the current array I have, and below it is a picture of the layout it needs to organized into (The red numbers refer to the first dimension of the array below. Bottom left quadrant refers to the second dimension.) I am intending to use pcolor, but am certainly open to other options if there's anything that would be better suited to this problem. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

```
[[  575.40625    984.40625    560.234375   936.0625     733.84375
    725.9375     469.234375   828.046875   210.421875   522.4375     713.375
    466.484375   679.8125     242.296875   645.328125   666.265625]
 [  976.390625   668.46875    513.328125   769.359375  1343.65625
   1068.3125    1206.21875   1447.484375   571.359375   420.71875
    246.03125    333.15625    626.921875   615.03125    867.03125
   1051.34375 ]
 [  498.1875    1176.453125   670.609375   597.578125   765.078125
    713.8125     825.84375    760.171875   667.015625   755.40625
   1003.71875    687.921875   448.921875   574.90625    598.859375
    487.09375 ]
 [  564.203125   485.140625   652.625      740.875      465.875     1152.03125
    623.15625    949.28125    722.515625   397.046875   529.03125    487.
    427.109375   424.         495.734375   510.453125]]
```

[image: Physical representation. The red numbers refer to the first dimension of the array above. Bottom left quadrant refers to the second dimension.]

Comment: The arrangement of your points is a space filling Z curve. Perhaps that helps you getting started.

Comment: Each row in the nested list you provided corresponds to a red box in the image below? If that's the case, then I see a problem. Each red box has the same number of elements, however, in your nested list, some have 6 elements and some have 5. Also, how would each nested list be distributed in the red boxes, i.e., column wise, row wise, some other way?

Comment: @MartinUeding Good point. Do you know of anything in numpy I can use where I could flatten the array and then use an algorithm to form the physical structure using a z order curve?

Comment: @FilipKilibarda The above array's dimensions are designated by the square brackets, not the physical rows. My apologies if that was unclear. The indices in the first dimension correspond to the red boxes, and the indices in the second dimension correspond to the black numbers (specifically in the bottom left, and then iterated three more times in the other red boxes).

Comment: @cadams, oh yeah, that should have been clear to me. My mistake.

Comment: Is your actual input simply a one-dimensional sequence (with 64 elements) that you want to plot as an 8x8 image, with the indices into the sequence as shown in your blue grid?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 8x8 grid is viewed as a two-dimensional numpy array, the row corresponding to a given index into the one-dimensional data is computed as the binary value of bits 1, 3, and 5 of the index.  Similarly, the column is computed using bits 0, 2 and 4 of the index.  Here's a function to convert an index to a row and column:

```
def row_col_coords(index):
    # Convert bits 1, 3 and 5 to row
    row = 4*((index & 0b100000) > 0) + 2*((index & 0b1000) > 0) + 1*((index & 0b10) > 0)
    # Convert bits 0, 2 and 4 to col
    col = 4*((index & 0b10000) > 0) + 2*((index & 0b100) > 0) + 1*((index & 0b1) > 0)
    return (row, col)
```

For example,

```
In [114]: row_col_coords(45)
Out[114]: (6, 3)
```

I.e. for index 45, `row` (i.e. `y`) is 6 and `col` is 3.

The calculations are vectorized, so the function actually handles an array of indices.  For example,

```
In [116]: row_col_coords(np.array([45, 46, 47, 48]))
Out[116]: (array([6, 7, 7, 4]), array([3, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Here's a sample one-dimensional data array with length 64.  It is simply [100, 101, 102, ..., 163] so we can easily see that the array is correct.

```
In [116]: data = 100 + np.arange(64.)
```

To form the 8x8 array, first create the row and column indices that correspond to the data indices [0, 1, 2, ..., 63]:

```
In [117]: row, col = row_col_coords(np.arange(64))
```

Now create an 8x8 array and fill it with `data`, using `row` and `col` to get the desired order:

```
In [118]: a = np.empty((8, 8))

In [119]: a[row, col] = data

In [120]: a
Out[120]: 
array([[ 100.,  101.,  104.,  105.,  116.,  117.,  120.,  121.],
       [ 102.,  103.,  106.,  107.,  118.,  119.,  122.,  123.],
       [ 108.,  109.,  112.,  113.,  124.,  125.,  128.,  129.],
       [ 110.,  111.,  114.,  115.,  126.,  127.,  130.,  131.],
       [ 132.,  133.,  136.,  137.,  148.,  149.,  152.,  153.],
       [ 134.,  135.,  138.,  139.,  150.,  151.,  154.,  155.],
       [ 140.,  141.,  144.,  145.,  156.,  157.,  160.,  161.],
       [ 142.,  143.,  146.,  147.,  158.,  159.,  162.,  163.]])
```

The rows are reversed!  That's because numpy arrays show row 0 first, then row 1, etc. To see the data in the "correct" order, just reverse the array:

```
In [121]: a[::-1]
Out[121]: 
array([[ 142.,  143.,  146.,  147.,  158.,  159.,  162.,  163.],
       [ 140.,  141.,  144.,  145.,  156.,  157.,  160.,  161.],
       [ 134.,  135.,  138.,  139.,  150.,  151.,  154.,  155.],
       [ 132.,  133.,  136.,  137.,  148.,  149.,  152.,  153.],
       [ 110.,  111.,  114.,  115.,  126.,  127.,  130.,  131.],
       [ 108.,  109.,  112.,  113.,  124.,  125.,  128.,  129.],
       [ 102.,  103.,  106.,  107.,  118.,  119.,  122.,  123.],
       [ 100.,  101.,  104.,  105.,  116.,  117.,  120.,  121.]])
```